# How to test if method was called in RxJs pipe function inside map operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

How to test if method was called in RxJs pipe function inside map operator?

```
 getName(): Observable<string> {
    return of('John').pipe(
      map((name) => {
        return this.convertName(name);
      })
    );
  }

convertName(name: string): string {
    return `${name}_observable`;
  }
```

Already tried:

```
  describe('getNameAndCallMethodAsync', () => {
    it('should call convertName', () => {
      spyOn(component, 'convertName');
      component.getNameAndCallMethodAsync().subscribe();
      expect(component.convertName()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

and it returns error `Expected a spy, but got 'undefined_observable'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `expect(component.convertName())`, the function is called, and the return value (a string) is checked, which isn't what you want.

Instead, you should provide the function itself, like `expect(component.convertName)`.